# Programmatically save Resource Dictionary to Disk

Tags: wpf, resources, save

I need to use a resource dictionary located in my local machine. My WPF application will add/remove items dynamically to that dictionary using Add() or Remove() methods. Once done I need to save the updated resource dictionary again to the disk.

I don't find a direct way for this. Is there anything like ResurceDictionary.Save()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XamlWriter` class.

Here's a piece of code that writes button's template to a file:

```
// Get the template.
ControlTemplate template = button.Template;

// Get the XAML for the template.
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\template.xaml", settings);
XamlWriter.Save(template, writer);
```

Comment: what's up with the StringBuilder?

Answer (score 2):

```
ResourceDictionary dic = Application.Current.Resources;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Themes\\NewOne.xaml");
XamlWriter.Save(dic, writer);
writer.Close();
```